# Why I use Split() function have Error in lightning component like this?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, salesforcedx

```
var selectedField = component.get("v.selectedField");
var resultArray = selectedField.split(',');
```

when I use split method display this error,who could tell me why?
Error:
Uncaught Action failed: [selectedField.split is not a function]

Comment: Without knowing what "selectedField" is, we have no way to tell you precisely, but clearly you're not using it on a String object.

Comment: "selectedField" is：<aura:attribute name="selectField" access="public" type="String" />

Comment: when I write this to test whether split method could use, it works.        var str = '55;99';
        str = str.replace(";","")
        console.log('str'+str);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks your help.
Because my `selectField` is used in  `lightning:select value="{!v.selectField}"`.
I add a `toString` method convert to `String` and now it works.

```
var resultArray = selectedField.toString().split(',');
```

Comment: Sometimes the values you get from an `aura:attribute` are weird wrapper objects built into Lightning instead of native JS objects. Or you might get something like an array containing one string instead of a string. So yeah you occasionally have to coerce it to the right type to manipulate it.

Comment: Now that you specify it's from `lightning:select` that makes sense. It's exactly as I was saying - it returns an array instead of one String, because the same component is also capable of multi-select.